# Did Lucas discover Lucas circles?

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, euclidean-geometry

MathWord's article on [Lucas circles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasCircles.html) traces the name to a little-known 1973 publication.  These interesting circles have found their way into several 21st century publications, including the online Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers.  Is there a reference to Édouard Lucas's discussion of these circles?

Answer (score 1):

This is what Paul Yiu [writes](http://math.fau.edu/Yiu/GeometryNotes020402.pdf) about the origin of the name:

> Éduoard Lucas (1842-1891) wrote about this triad of circles,
>   considered by an anonymous author, as the three circles mutually
>   tangent to each other and each tangent to the circumcircle at a vertex
>   of ABC. The [[construction](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LucasCircles/) in terms of] inscribed squares was found by Victor
>   Thébault (1883-1960).

Thébault's paper is summarized [here.](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:63.1178.03) So it seems the name "Lucas circles" goes back to this 1937 source.

I presume Lucas's source is his Récréations mathématiques (1882-1894), but I have not yet located it there.